# Abrir uma nova Activity de dentro de um Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

Como faço para sair da tela do fragment (`extends Fragment`) e ir para uma Activity normal (`extends AppCompatActivity`)? Seja de qualquer forma, até usando um botão, eu não consigo. Nunca dá certo.

```
public class Teste extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.botao_tela_status) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.conteudo_fragmento, new FragmentoStatusTela()).commit();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_quiz_tela) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.conteudo_fragmento, new FragmentoQuiz()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.desafio2) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Teste.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.desafio3) {

    } else if (id == R.id.desafio4) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

```css
12-18 17:32:17.776 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
12-18 17:32:17.790 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-18 17:32:17.791 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia, PID: 3532
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia.Main2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:471)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:325)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                        at com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
12-18 17:32:20.471 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3532 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao abrir nova Activity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17633/erro-ao-abrir-nova-activity)

Comment: E Como posso resolver ? por favor me ajude

Comment: Leia a resposta aceita da outra pergunta. É aquilo ali.

Comment: eu fiz isso o continua com o erro

Comment: vale lembrar que estou usando uma classe com a extensão Fragment

Comment: É parecido, mas vou colocar uma resposta específica pra fragments aqui então. Só um minuto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando o StackTrace, o problema está no tema do aplicativo. Você deve adicionar as seguintes linhas no tema para que essa reação funcione:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

---

**Versão antiga da resposta:**

Analisando os comentários anteriores o problema parece ser um NullException no acionamento do botão.

> Desculpa Pablo, mas ainda não da certo porque se eu vou no xml e coloco o onClick="click_aqui" e executo o aplicativo já fecha

Como você está chamando o evento através do XML, ele deve estar resultando em um NullException do Botão por não estar sendo inflado corretamente. Como você não postou nenhum trecho de código, não posso dar certeza nisso.

Mas de qualquer forma, tente alterar algumas coisas no seu código, por exemplo:

**No XML:**
Remova o "onClick" do botão e adicione um ID para ele.

**No Fragment, faça:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.id_btn);

     /*
     * Define a ação do Botão, é o mesmo que você está fazendo através do 
     * onClick no XML.
     */
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentActivity act = getActivity();

            if (act != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(act, OutraActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Por favor, note que o trecho *"R.layout.fragment"* deve ser o nome do seu layout e *"R.id.id_btn"* deve ser o ID que você deu ao botão.

Comment: Olhe ai meu código acabei de colocar e ele assim da errado não sei porque

Comment: Poderia postar o erro que está acontecendo, por favor. E se possível, o código do Fragment também.

Comment: acabei de colocar o erro

Comment: Ok, vendo o StackTrace, podemos perceber que o problema é outro.. Tente colocar no tema do seu aplicativo `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: Muito obrigado Amelco, deu certo, era só isso, você é demais

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Alterei a minha resposta com essa solução.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do evento que vai fazer abrir a nova tela (botão, por exemplo), você vai colocar algo assim:

```
Intent abrirOutraActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), OutraActivity.class);
startActivity(abrirOutraActivity);
```

A diferença aqui em relação a abrir por dentro de uma Activity é que você vai usar `getActivity()` no lugar de `this` ou `MinhaActivity.this`, porque esse primeiro parâmetro do construtor do `Intent` tem que ser um `Context` e o `Fragment` não é um `Context` (mas a Activity dentro da qual ele está é)

Comment: Desculpa Pablo, mas ainda não da certo porque se eu vou no xml e coloco o onClick="click_aqui" e executo o aplicativo já fecha

Comment: Acho que vou desistir

Comment: Ver Você cria um NavigationDrawer usando o modelo do android studio e tenta chamar uma activity pelo menu para ver o que acontece, por favor me ajude